# Dead letters in akka remoting (scala)

Tags: scala, akka, remoting

I am encountering dead letters when I try to run a simple example using remote akka actors on my localhost.

This is my build.sbt file for the remote project.

```
name := "HelloRemote"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.6"
)
```

This is my application.conf file for remote system.

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
   }
   remote {
     enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
     netty.tcp {
       hostname = "127.0.0.1"
       port = 5100
     }
   }
}
```

This is my HelloRemote.scala file for the remote system.

```
package remote

import akka.actor._

object HelloRemote extends App  {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloRemoteSystem")
  val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteActor], name = "RemoteActor")
  remoteActor ! "The RemoteActor is alive"
}

class RemoteActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
        println(s"RemoteActor received message '$msg'")
        sender ! "Hello from the RemoteActor"
  }
}
```

For my local system, the build.sbt file is as follows.

```
name := "HelloLocal"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.6"
)
```

The application.conf file for my local system is

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
  }
}
```

And the HelloLocal.scala file for my local system is

```
package local

import akka.actor._

object Local extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("LocalSystem")
  val localActor = system.actorOf(Props[LocalActor], name = "LocalActor")  // the local actor
  localActor ! "START"                                                     // start the action

}

class LocalActor extends Actor {

  // create the remote actor
  val remote = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5100/user/RemoteActor")
  var counter = 0

  def receive = {
    case "START" =>
        remote ! "Hello from the LocalActor"
    case msg: String =>
        println(s"LocalActor received message: '$msg'")
        if (counter < 5) {
            sender ! "Hello back to you"
            counter += 1
        }
  }
}
```

When I first run HelloRemote.scala `The RemoteActor is alive` gets printed as expected and then I immediately get the error

```
[INFO] [09/16/2014 10:52:47.585] [HelloRemoteSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatche
r-4] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Acto
r[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/user/RemoteActor#1051175275] to Actor[akka://HelloRem
oteSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This log
ging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-le
tters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I get a similar error when I run the local system HelloLocal.scala and then nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

When you send a message from outside an actor, Akka fills in the dead letters mailbox as the sender.  When your `RemoteActor` in `HelloRemote.scala` replies, it's replying to the dead letters mailbox since the message it received was sent outside an actor.

At the moment, remoting isn't even involved in `HelloRemote.scala` since you're only deploying a local actor.

When you run `HelloLocal.scala`, I suspect your `HelloRemote` actor system is terminating since there's nothing to keep that main running.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying but I'm still not sure what I will have to change in my code to get it working. Should I just remove the part where I'm sending a message from outside the actor in HelloRemote.scala

Comment: The dead letter comes from the reply to the message "The RemoteActor is alive" because there is no sender, as Ryan pointed out.

Apart from that you sample is working!

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem before, and I solved it by using `val config = ConfigFactory.parsingString("---Configuration---")` instead of using configuration file. 
Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you; After one day of banging my head to find why this dead letter was coming when running in java console, tried this and it worked. Amen to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well then doing the same example. The part that I missed was putting the application.conf in the src/main/resources directory.

You should see INFO messages like these if it is in the correct location when starting the server:

```
[INFO] [03/02/2016 19:06:10.365] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [03/02/2016 19:06:10.497] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses : akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5100]
[INFO] [03/02/2016 19:06:10.499] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5100]
```

The directory structure from the [blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-akka-actors-remote-example) I was following:

```
HelloRemote/
|-- build.sbt
|-- src
    |-- main
    │   |-- java
    │   |-- resources
    │   │   +-- application.conf <--------------------------
    │   +-- scala
    │       +-- remote
    │           +-- HelloRemote.scala
    +-- test
        |-- java
        |-- resources
        +-- scala
```

As already mentioned by [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853125/ryan) the dead letter error is a side effect of the String message "The RemoteActor is alive" not being an actor so it can not receive the message "Hello from the RemoteActor" back. It is a slight bug with the example but does not cause the failure of the remote and local actors to not be able to talk to each other.